# Creating a comma separated array in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file with contents as the following .

```
line1  
line2  
line3
```

I need to create array like this

```
('line2','line2','line3')
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: you want to create a Bash array or a string with the text `('line2','line2','line3')`?

Comment: @fedorqui A string with the text ('line2','line2','line3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The should help you :

```
sed -r "s/^|$/'/g" file | echo "(`paste -d, -s`)"
```

I'm using `sed` to add `'` in start & end of each line, then concatenate the content using `paste` and enclosing it with parenthesis using `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 while read line; do printf "'$line',"; done < file | sed 's/^/(/;s/,$/)\n/'
```

The `while` loop gets the content and enclose it between brackets.

`s/^/(/` is adding a `(` at the beginning of the string.

`s/,$/)\n/` is replacing the last `,` by a `)` and a cariage return.

Comment: Thank you oliv , your answer got worked partially . It didn't print the last line, Can you pls explain the code sed 's/^/(/;s/,$/)\n/'

Comment: I gave a bit more explanation. Can you edit your question with the real input file? The one you put is working...

Comment: Olive, I got that part. Thank You
when I tested the last line was not there in the array. Also how inverted commas and coma delimiters are coming, just wanted to know ?

Comment: Comma and quotes are part of the `printf` statement